How to fix error message : "Error in map(fit.832.rp, what = "rerouted") : argument ".f" is missing, with no default" when using Animotum package
I am having trouble with fit an ssm using a move persistence model. This is the code I run: map_plot_832=map(fit.832.rp, what = "rerouted") + ggtitle("832, 2023MX-Mno-00832, Adult")
I am trying to make a plot/map. The error is the following:
Error in map(fit.832.rp, what = "rerouted") :
argument ".f" is missing, with no default
Here is a snipet of my code:
enc_correct_time=mdy_hms(enc.argos$timevalue) #transforms from a character into read mode
enc_correct_time=with_tz(enc_correct_time,tzone="US/Central") #change time to Mexico
ssm.data=cbind(enc.argos,enc_correct_time)

#Change abbreviations
ssm.data <- ssm.data %>% rename("lon" = "longitude") %>% 
  rename("lat" = "latitude") %>% rename("smaj" = "semi_major") %>% 
  rename("smin" = "semi_minor") %>% rename("eor" = "ellipse") %>% 
  rename("id" = "animal_name") %>% rename("lc" = "loc_class") %>% 
  rename("date" = "enc_correct_time")

#Eliminate NA's
ssm.data=ssm.data %>% slice(0:3451)

#separating them by each tag - DO THIS FOR ALL TAGS 

#####Tag 832
ssm.832.data=ssm.data%>%subset(ptt==832)

       ####model fits by tag 
m.832.rp <- fit_ssm(ssm.832.data,
                    model = "mp",
                    time.step = 6) #every 6 hours give me location and makes a track #DOES NOT WORK 

fit.832.rp=route_path(m.832.rp,what="predicted",
                       map_scale=10,
                       buffer=500)

final.tracks.832=grab(fit.832.rp,what="rerouted") #saving a new data set with updated location 

map_plot=map(fit.832.rp,what="rerouted") +ggtitle ("832, tag_name (or ID?), social class")
#Example: map(fit.832.rp, what = "rerouted") + ggtitle("832, 2023MX-Mno-00832, Adult")

map_plot_832=map(fit.832.rp, what = "rerouted") + ggtitle("832, 2023MX-Mno-00832, Adult") **-THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR SHOWS UP.**


I tried restarting R, changed the version to the newest one. Etc. And the error still pops up.

purrr::map() is used to apply a function to a list or vector. Your first argument should be the list or vector. The  .f argument is the function. If you are not trying to apply a function to a list or vector, then you would not use map(). What are you attempting to do with map()?

I am trying to make a plot/map using each satellite tag.
